# Best practise to handling large datasets(image) on cloud by a python tensorflow script in a VM

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, dataset, google-cloud-storage

Dataset of GB size sitting in Google storage has to be accessed from  a VM to train and test a tensorflow model. Accesing all the 17500 images is very slow because of GCS latency. The other way is to zip the dataset and download it to the VM. However, this is will raise memory issues. Hence what is the best approach to handle data in this situation

Current approach: Download the zip file locally, and access individual images after extraction of the .zip file. How to download the dataset in parts having the .zip folder in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use `TFRECORD` format. You can find documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord).

`TFRECORD` is a efficient storage mode for large dataset. It's optimized for reading shuffling and all other important things in ML training.

However, nothing is magic. You have to download locally this file (or these files if you make several) and then work with it efficiency for your training. GB is not huge. Each VM has at least 10 or 20Gb of disk. For good I/O, it's recommended to use disk with at least 200Gb.